# All Draconid Locations in the witcher 3?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I think I've killed every last draconid lol any rare or not well known ones? I need to finish mastercrafted ursine armor. I was stupid and sold all the hides.

Comment: I'd say it's to early for people to have done this kind of research into the game sadly.

Answer (score 3):

You can purchase Cured Draconid Hide from the Master Armorsmith in Crow's Perch and also from the Master Weaponsmith, Hattori, in Novigrad. I've made mastercrafted ursine and feline almost exclusively using the cured draconid from the vendors, they have plenty. I believe other blacksmiths sell the reagent as well, like the armorsmith near the an Craite castle in Skellige.